# How do I run Windows Server Backup?

Tags: backup, windows, windows-server-2012

I'm running WS2012 as a workstation OS. I want to use Windows Server Backup to backup everything on my internal hard drive to my external hard drive.

Windows Server Backup displays a message like this in the Local Backup panel:

> Windows Server Backup is not installed on this computer. To install Windows Server Backup, from Server Manager select "Add roles and features", and follow the wizard to select the Windows Server Backup feature.

I have already installed the feature using a PowerShell script like this:

```
Install-WindowsFeature Windows-Server-Backup
```

You have to run it as Administrator. As a user you receive a permissions error like this:

```
Install-WindowsFeature : You do not have adequate user rights to make changes to the target computer. If you are
already a member of the Administrators group on the target computer, the changes might have failed because of security
restrictions imposed by User Account Control. Try running Install-WindowsFeature in a Windows PowerShell session that
has been opened with elevated rights (Run as administrator).
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-WindowsFeature Windows-Server-Backup
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (@{Vhd=; Credent...Name=localhost}:PSObject) [Install-WindowsFeature],
    Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Provider_UserIsNotAdmininistrator,Microsoft.Windows.ServerManager.Commands.AddWindowsFea
   tureCommand
```

As Administrator you receive output like this:

```
Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result                           
------- -------------- ---------      --------------                           
True    No             Success        {Windows Server Backup}
```

The output indicates no restart is required, but I have restarted to be sure.

Am I missing something that the wizard would handle for me?

Answer (score 1):

#### Run Windows Server Backup as Administrator

The Windows Server Backup feature is all you have to install to use the program.

You have to run Windows Server Backup as Administrator, otherwise you receive the misleading message.

Backing up all the computer's data is usually an administrative task, so it makes sense the the program should require administrative rights.

This method of backup is convenient for a workstation setup. If you were working in a multi-user environment, or didn't have administrative rights, you might want to use user-level backup tools instead.

#### The messaging is misleading

Microsoft could improve the messaging to avoid confusion. For example, Device Manager displays a message to users before it runs. The message looks like this:

> You are logged on as a standard user. You can view device settings in device manager, but you must be logged on as an administrator to make changes.

This message makes it clear that Device Manager that it restricts some of its functionality to users.